# Trying to make the filters to persist when im changing page (server side)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, axios, pagination

im calling an endpoint that filters the results with pagination onPressEnter event that's inside the Input tag, but i'm trying to paginate the filtered results and i'm currently fetching all filtered results, however when i click on the next page to see the next filtered results, the table shows other results, because the pagination its also being called on another endpoint that fetches all data(without filters) the code looks like this

```html
const ParentComponent => () {
 const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
   const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState([]);
   const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
   const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(7);

  useEffect(() => {
      const getValues = () => {
         const limit = pageSize * (page - 1)
         setLoading(true);
         axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/elements?skip=${limit}&&take=${pageSize}`)
            .then((res) => {
               console.log('firstRender', res.data.data);
               setValues(res.data.data);
               setPageCount(res.data.count);
            })
            .catch(errorHandling)
            .finally(() => {
               setLoading(false);
            });
      };
      getValues();
   }, [page]);
}

 const handlePageSize = (value: number) => {
      setPageSize(value);
   };

   const handlePag`enter code here`eCount = (value) => {
      setPageCount(value);
   };

   const handleCurrentPage = (value: number) => {
      setPage(value);
   };

   const handleValue = (value: SetStateAction<never[]>) => {
     setValues(value);
   };

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
const {allthepropsfromtheParentComponent} = props
    return (
(this is the column where im searching)const columns = [
      {
         title: 'dealership',
         width: 125,
         dataIndex: 'Dealership',
         key: 'Dealership',
         fixed: 'left',
  filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm,clearFilters }) => {
               <div style={{ padding: 8, width: '12.8rem' }}>
                  <Input
                     autoFocus
                     placeholder="Enter dealership"
                     value={selectedKeys[0]}
                     onChange={(e) => {
                        setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : []);
                        
                     }}
                     onPressEnter={async () => {
                       const limit = pageSize * (page - 1)
                        confirm(
                        await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/elements?name=${selectedKeys}&&skip=${limit}&&take=${pageSize}`)
                        .then(res => { 
                           return  setSelectedKeys(res.data), 
                                  handleValue(res.data.data),
                                  handlePageCount(res.data.count)}).catch(err => console.log(err)))                  
                     }}
                  />
}
 return (
      <>
         <Table
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={handleRenditionData(renditionValues)}
            loading={loading}
            scroll={{ x: 1300 }}
            pagination={{
               pageSize: pageSize,
               current: page,
               total: pageCount && pageCount,
               onChange: (page, pageSize) => {
                  handlePageSize(pageSize);
                  const apiURL = `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/elements?   skip=${page}&&take=${pageSize}`;
                  axios.get(apiURL).then((response) => {
                     console.log(response.data), handleValue(response.data.data), handlePageCount(response.data.count + 1), handleCurrentPage(page);
                  });
               }
            }}
            size="middle"
         />
      </>
}
```

the pagination by all elements is being fetched correctly when im clicking, but now that i try to fetch the the filtered names onPressEnter, i can get all the corresponding values, but i want the filter to persist when i change the page (for example, if im getting 10 elements per page, get them filtered on each page click if the filter is selecte), which now, every time that i click the next page it brings me all the data again, i hope im explaining myself well,
Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: i couldn't find any filter in your code... how do you handle that? you just have some states to store the page size or number...

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the filter prop before api endpoint in my question, i updated the question, the filter is made inside a prop which calls the endpoint im using and then storing it on the state

Comment: you can use localStorage to persist the filter items... use something like `localstorage-slim` to handle localStorage